# Inner and outer limit of sets sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I study functional analysis by a ukrainian book, and I'm stuck with one problem:
prove that
$$
\bar{\lim}_{n\to \infty}\hat{A}_n=lower \lim_{n\to\infty}\hat{A}_n
$$

Is there a mistake in the book, or am I wrong?

$$
\cup_{n=1}^\infty \cap_{m=n}^\infty \hat{A}_m = \cap_{n=1}^\infty \cup_{m=n}^\infty \hat{A}_m
$$

$$\cup_{n=1}^\infty \cap_{m=n}^\infty \hat{A}_m = \cup_{n=1}^\infty \overline{\cup_{m=n}^\infty A_m}=\overline{\cap_{n=1}^\infty (\cup_{m=n}^\infty A_m)}$$
$$
\cap_{n=1}^\infty \cup_{m=n}^\infty \hat{A}_m = \cap_{n=1}^\infty \overline{\cap_{m=n}^\infty A_m} = \overline{\cup_{n=1}^\infty (\cap_{m=n}^\infty A_m)}
$$
It follows than $\cup_{n=1}^\infty (\cap_{m=n}^\infty A_m) = \cap_{n=1}^\infty (\cup_{m=n}^\infty A_m)$, but that's wrong, as I guess.

Comment: Do you mean $\limsup$ (also called $\varlimsup$) and $\liminf$ (also called $\varliminf$)?  If so, they're not _always_ equal, so does the problem also contain some assumption about the $\hat{A}_n$'s? And does the "hat" on the $A_n$'s have a meaning that is relevant to the problem?

Comment: @Trevor Wilson. Yes, this is what I mean. $\hat{A}_n$ is complement set, $A'$, as it is denoted in western countries.

Comment: The statement becomes true if you take one of the hats away, as you have shown above.

Comment: @Thomas, Yes, I got it now. Poor quality of e-version of the book.